# jQuery Closest/Parent not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, closest

What's going wrong in this code? Nothing happens on click

HTML

```
  <p>Click me</p>
    <h1 class="myClass">...........</h1>

  <p>Click me</p>
    <h1 class="myClass">-----------</h1>
```

CSS

```
hilight {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
```

jQuery

```
$( document ).on( "click", "p", function( ) {
  $( this ).closest( ".myClass" ).toggleClass( "hilight" );
});
```

Live example
https://jsfiddle.net/djuccj7b/

Comment: Those `<h1>` elements are not parent elements of your `<p>` elements. The `.closest()` method looks up the parent chain from the source element.

Comment: In this case they are `next()`. That being said...when in doubt, check in jQuery API that the traverse method you are using is appropriate. There are examples for all methods

Comment: I believe your use of `$(this)` is referring to `$(document)`.

Comment: this refer to paragraph (alert(this) to check)  the problem was closest to next and the missing dot in css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change closest() to next()
2. Put a period in front of your class name in the css....

   .hilight {
       background-color: yellow;
     }

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Next Adjacent Selector ("prev + next")](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/) with [`context`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) set to `this` : `p` element to select `h1` element that is next element sibling of clicked `p` element

```
$( document ).on( "click", "p", function( ) {
  $( "+ .myClass", this ).toggleClass( "hilight" );
});
```

Also, your `css` is missing `.` before `hilight`

```
.hilight {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/djuccj7b/2/